# .Net task scheduler behaviour

Tags: .net, async-await, task

I played around with .Net tasks, given the following code:

```
    public static async Task TaskSchedulerBehaviour()
    {
        var topLevelTasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(async n =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(50); // THIS LINE MAKES THE DIFFERENCE
            var steps = Enumerable.Range(0, 100000);
            foreach (var batch in steps.Batch(1000)) { /* ".Batch" is contained in MoreLinq */
                await Task.WhenAll(batch.Select(async step => await WorkStep(n, step)));
            }
        });
        await Task.WhenAll(topLevelTasks);

        async Task WorkStep(int worker, int step)
        {
            if (step % 100 == 0) {
                Console.WriteLine($"worker={worker}, step={step}");
            }

            await Task.Delay(10);
        }
    }
```

The shown code contains some "large" top-level tasks which do a lot of work (=many small tasks (`WorkStep`); which only call `Task.Delay`).

One line in the code is marked with a comment: If this line is removed it might happen that some of the top-level tasks are queued until all the others are done. It seems they can starve if the other "top-level" tasks are very very intensive.

On the other side, if I add the commented line, the behaviour is much nicer: It seems that all top-level tasks get a more or less similar amount of time to execute their child-tasks. They run concurrent.

Why does this happen? Isn't the task scheduler a simple FIFO-queue or something like this?

Thank you very much

Comment: By adding this line you make the rest of the method a continuation, without this line the task will start executing up to the first await before it returns.

Comment: All child tasks of a "top-level task" use `Task.Delay` and therefore block the top-level task.

Comment: The problem is the code itself. The task scheduler schedules tasks. It's not a queue. You can't use it as if it were a queue. Tasks aren't messages either. If you want ETL-style processing use the TPL Dataflow classes like ActionBlock. The blocks contain their own input/output buffers. They can be combined into processing pipelines, with each block running on its own task. BatchBlock can batch incoming messages. It's also possible to process multiple messages in parallel by setting the MaxDegreeOfParallelism setting

Comment: Assuming the *real* "big" tasks generate a lot of smaller tasks you could use a TransformManyBlock to receive the "big" input and produce multiple outputs that will be sent to subsequent blocks for processing

Comment: Another option is to just use PLINQ. Both PLINQ and Parallel.ForEach partition the data and feed each batch to a separate task for processing. This way, each CPU core can work at 100% processing data instead of trying to synchronize access to a common queue

Comment: Thanks for these hints. I will have a look at TPL Dataflow.

I am still wondering how the TaskScheduler chooses the next task to handle. FIFO? FILO? I won't create code that depends on this behaviour, but i am still wondering how this is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the thread pool task scheduler, which is one of many possible task schedulers...

> Why does this happen? Isn't the task scheduler a simple FIFO-queue or something like this?

[There is one shared queue that is generally (not strictly) FIFO, plus each thread pool thread has its own local queue that is generally (not strictly) LIFO](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jennifer/2009/06/26/work-stealing-in-net-4-0/). Thread pool threads can steal from other thread's local queues if they have nothing to do.

Also, task schedulers are used to execute *synchronous code only*. The concept of `async`/`await` is a level of abstraction above task schedulers. So, by adding an `await Task.Delay`, your code is actually splitting one conceptual `async` task into multiple parts, each of which is queued to the thread pool at the appropriate time. I.e., the first part is queued immediately; when it runs, it calls `Task.Delay` (starting a timer) and then hits the `await`, causing that part to exit; when the timer goes off, the second part is queued immediately.

For real-world code, as Panagiotis stated in the comments, consider [TPL Dataflow](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/) for queueing work.

Comment: I see, LIFO is used because of caching:)! Sounds reasonable. Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer to your question. I'm just offering an alternative that is a lot nicer than using tasks directly.

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
public static async Task TaskSchedulerBehaviour()
{
    var topLevelTasks =
        from n in Observable.Range(0, 5)
        from batch in Observable.Range(0, 100000).Buffer(1000)
        from results in
            from step in batch.ToObservable()
            from result in Observable.FromAsync(() => WorkStep(n, step))
            select result
        select results;

    await topLevelTasks.ToArray();

    async Task WorkStep(int worker, int step)
    {
        if (step % 100 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"worker={worker}, step={step}");
        }
        await Task.Delay(10);
    }
}
```

Rx handles all of the scheduling very nicely for you.

You have to admit that the code looks a lot nicer too.